# How do i play Youtube videos in webview?

Tags: android, flash, video, webview, youtube

I am a noob to android and despite the numerous tutorials I have read i still can't figure out how to play youtube videos in my webview.  I can navigate the site without any problem, but when i click on a video nothing happens.  I have tried adding android:hardwareAccelerated="true" to my manifest with no success. Any help is greatly appreciated.  Here is what i have so far:

```
  huffingtonpost = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    huffingtonpost.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    huffingtonpost.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    huffingtonpost.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    huffingtonpost.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    huffingtonpost.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    try{
    huffingtonpost.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/KitcoNews");
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My manifest

```
 <application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code sample:

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.webview_compontent );

String playVideo= "<html><body>Youtube video .. <br> <iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"640\" height=\"385\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/bIPcobKMB94\" frameborder=\"0\"></body></html>"

myWebView.loadData(playVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

If the URL is getted from a EditText or something else, you can just manipulate the String `playVideo`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  This approach works for watching a single video, but i want to be able to view video on a channel or playlist page as one would when normally navigating the site.  This is the channel url i'm trying to view http://www.youtube.com/KitcoNews, which shows fine in the device browser.  Do you know how to display that in webview?

Comment: @B.Money I don't know how to do so. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

**How to play Youtube Channel in android webview?**

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
   @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          //setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String html="http://www.youtube.com/KitcoNews";
          // Let's display the progress in the activity title bar, like the
          // browser app does.
          getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

          WebView webview = new WebView(this);
          setContentView(webview);

          webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

          final Activity activity = this;
          webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
          public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

             activity.setTitle("Loading...");
                activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

                if(progress == 100)
                    activity.setTitle(""Done);

          }
        });


webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
          //Users will be notified in case there's an error (i.e. no internet connection)
          Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
 });
       //This will load the webpage that we want to see
        webview.loadUrl(html);

     }
    }
```